# Having issues fixing site speed

Tags: cache

G'day!

My website > www.captiveoudoor.com generally takes about 50-60 seconds to load all resources, which is currently killing our traffic and google ranking.

After running pagespeed insights I noticed that some issues need fixing: 1. browser caching, 2. optimzing CSS resources, 3. image optimization.

1. I am using W3 Total cache to deal with this issue.
2. No fix in the pipeline for this
3. The image optimization issue I tried to fix with the Smushit plugin - but it looks as though I need to opt in to a full paid version to take full advantage.

With not a lot of understanding if this is the case, I also fear that I have too many plugins that may be affecting site speed times, but this may be totally unfounded.

Any sugguestions or questions? I am more than happy to answer them.

Thanks so much,

- Tony

Comment: Hello there. If your server supports lscache, i recommend you Litespeed Cache Plugin. https://tr.wordpress.org/plugins/litespeed-cache/ plugin works with server and create critical css, async load of css and js. Also have HTTP2 & QUIC support. 

for image optimization, (if your server supports) i recommend ewww image optimizer for optimizing images https://tr.wordpress.org/plugins/ewww-image-optimizer/ both plugin is free

Answer (score 0):

Please Use this plugin to increase Performance

https://wordpress.org/plugins/fast-velocity-minify/